# GCC check the reference type is same with value

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

It's amazing that std::set be converted to MySet, but how to avoid ?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct MySet : public std::set<int> {
  MySet(const std::set<int>& s) {
  }
};

std::set<int> get(int i) {
  return std::set<int>{i};
}

int main() {
  const MySet& a = get(0);
  std::cout << a.empty() << std::endl;  // true
}
```

`const MySet& a = get(0);` should give compile error.

Comment: Why add the constructor if you don't want this behavior?

Comment: You have a converting constructor that converts a `std::set` to a `MySet`.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and then *never* include that header ever again.

Comment: Make the constructor `explicit`.

Comment: The constructor `MySet(const std::set<int>& s)` is a so-called *converting* constructor. It allows implicit conversion from `std::set<int>` to `MySet`.

Comment: So the reference isn't bound to a `std::set`, but to a `MySet` constructed from `get(0)`. A const reference can be bound to a temporary, so that's what happens here.

Comment: I'm also very curious about why you need `MySet`. And why you need to mix `std::set` and `MySet` like you do with `const MySet& a = get(0)` What is the actual and underlying problem that `MySet` and `get` are supposed to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> const MySet& a = get(0); should compile error

This can be done either by removing the converting ctor `MySet::MySet(const std::set<int>&)`or by making it **explicit** as shown below:

```
struct MySet : public std::set<int> {
//vvvvvvvv---------------------------------->make this ctor explicit
  explicit MySet(const std::set<int>& s) {
  }
};

int main() {
  const MySet& a = get(0);
  std::cout << a.empty() << std::endl;  // gives error now
}
```